# How get raw answer data in QWebEngineView?

Tags: qt, http, qwebengineview

Next examples work on small html pages, but dont work if page return big html data or json

I try this after loadFinished signal

```
    view->page()->toHtml([cc](const QString &result){
        qDebug() << "result ready";
        qDebug() << "result string ="<<result;
    });
```

I see "result ready", but second string not print, also I try this:

```
    v->page()->runJavaScript("function jsfun(){return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;};");
    //v->page()->runJavaScript("alert(jsfun())"); //work correctly
    v->page()->runJavaScript("jsfun();",[this](const QVariant &v) {
        qDebug() << "result ready";
        qDebug() << "result string ="<<v.toString();
    });
```

but again dont see second string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All example work correctly, but if buffer very big `qDebug` dont print data, you can write data to file or print part of data

Example (call toHtml after loadFinished signal) :

```
view->page()->toHtml([cc](const QString &result){ 
    QFile file("outerHTML.html");
    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
         qDebug() << "Cannot create a file";
         return;
    }
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << buff;
    file.close();
}
```